# Expresión regular que haga match sólo con el punto o los puntos que esten acompañado de números

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy intentando crear una expresión regular que haga match sólo con los puntos que estan acompañado de números ej:

- .       False
- ..      False
- ...     False
- .1      True
- .1.2    True
- .1.2.3  True

De momento tengo esta expresión regular:

```
\.\d
```

Pero me selecciona el punto y el primero número y solo quiero que haga match con el punto de los que tienen números. Si alguien tiene una idea de como puedo hacerlo, agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Entiendo que necesitas un "positive lookahead" `\.(?=\d)`

Comment: Exacto muchas gracias @Emeeus

Answer (score 0):

tal como @Emeeus explicó en el comentario, lo que necesitas es lo llamado *positive lookahead*. Básicamente, permite obtener un elemento basándose en lo que llegará más adelante, pero sin hacer match con eso.

En tu caso, estás intentando hacer match con un punto que, a continuación, tenga un dígito. Teniendo en cuenta que necesitas hacer match, la primera parte está perfecta: `\.` nos detectará un punto.

A continuación, debe tener un dígito, pero NO debe hacer match. Aquí utilizaremos el *positive lookahead*, que se define entre paréntesis, y con un símbolo de interrogación y un igual. Es decir, algo así: `(?=regex)` (sustituyendo regex con la expresión regular deseada).

Teniendo esto en cuenta, y sabiendo que debe ser un dígito lo que haya a continuación (la representación de dígito es `\d`, como bien has dicho), la expresión quedaría así:

```
/\.(?=\d)/
```

Como resumen:

- `/`: empezamos la expresión regular
- `\.`: que haga match con un punto
- `(?=\d)`: a continuación, debe haber un dígito, pero NO hagas match

  - `(`: empezamos el *positive lookahead*
  - `?=`: especificamos que a continuación debe haber...
  - `\d`: un dígito
  - `)`: finalizamos el *positive lookahead*
- `/`: finalizamos la expresión regular

¡Espero que te haya servido!